# How to load a file as a text string into some var with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So we have a `/page.html` and `/folder/file.bla`. We want to load that file contents as text string into some var using jQuery and call some function when we are done loading. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the file using $.AJAX :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/mypage.html',
    success: function (file_html) {
        // success
        alert('success : ' + file_html);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the goal of the OP is to load `'/folder/file.bla'` from `'/mypage.html'`.

Comment: Then add this code in your /mypage.html and load /folder/file.bla into the string ...Same thing.

Answer (score 7):

```
$.get('/folder/file.bla', function(data) {
  var fileContents = data;
});
```

The function you pass as the second argument to the [`get()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) will be run once the data has been loaded from the external URL.

Comment: You can add .success(function(){ }) after the }) ... also there's more event handler so you can manage this,

Answer (score 3):

What type is the file?
If its pure text, it shouldn't be a problem :)

```
   $.get('/folder/file.bla', function(data) {
    var filetxt = data;
    // FINISHED GETTING FILE, INSERT CODE
    });
```